# Using a custom comparator

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I've checked a bunch of similar questions but am still very confused. Anyway this was for an assignment that's been and gone.

I have a Present class:

```
public class Present implements PresentInterface{

private String name;
private String type;
private double cost;

public Present() {   
}

public Present(String name, String type, double cost) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.cost = cost;
}
```

and then a bunch of code for getting and setting the values.
I have a Child class which contains a bunch of info about the child.
I have a GiftList class which is an arraylist of presents. Each giftlist is associated with at most one child.
I then have a GiftSelector class which is an arraylist of GiftLists.
I would like to have a method in the giftSelector class that creates a hashmap with the keys being children, and the values being a list of presents sorted by cost.
So far I have:

```
    public HashMap<Child, ArrayList<Present>> sortList(){

    HashMap<Child, ArrayList<Present>> presentMap = new HashMap<Child, ArrayList<Present>>();
    ArrayList<Present> presentList = new ArrayList<Present>();

    for (GiftList giftList : giftSelector){
        presentList.clear();//clears the present list with each iteration otherwise 
        //each child would be paired with a list of presents containing those 
        //of the child before.

        Child mapChild = giftList.getChild();

        for (Present present : giftList.getAllPresents()){
            presentList.add(present);//goes through each present in the giftlist and adds it to presentlist
        }

        Collections.sort(presentList, new Comparator<Present>());

        presentMap.put(mapChild, presentList);
    }
    return presentMap;
}
}
```

The comparator isn't defined so of course it doesn't work. Do I define the comparator in the Present class or in the giftSelector class or do I give it an entirely new class of its own?
I think I need something like this somewhere:

```
public int compare(Present p1, Present p2){
    if (p1==null || p2 == null){
        return 0;
    }
    return p1.getCost().compareTo(p2.getCost());
}
```

and then some stuff which involves overriding and setting the compareTo values and other bits of magic. Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Incidentally, when I take out the Collections.sort(presentList, comparator) bit of the sortList() method, it compiles and runs fine, except that each child in the presentMap has the same value. They all have an arraylist containing the presents of the last giftlist that was iterated through. I've probably missed something obvious though.

Comment: That's because you're still operating on the same instance of presentList, instantiated before the loop. Instead of adding new list to map, you still referencing the old one and just clearing it each iteration.

Comment: @user4474022. Did my answer help? If so please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define it as a static member class:

```
public class Present implements PresentInterface {
    public static class CostComparator implements Comparator<Present >
    {
        public int compare(Present p1, Present p2)
        {
            // use either this line for null
            if (p1 == null || p2 == null) throw new NullPointerException();
            // or these 2 lines for null:
            if (p1 == null) return p2 == null ? 0 : -1;
            if (p2 == null) return 1;
            // and now do a reference check for speed
            if (p1 == p2) return 0;
            // and finally the value checks
            return Double.compare(p1.cost, p2.cost);
        }
    }
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private double cost;
}
```

There are two alternatives for `null` ordering (as shown) as [per the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> Unlike Comparable, a comparator may optionally permit comparison of null arguments, while maintaining the requirements for an equivalence relation

Putting it inside the `Present` class just makes it easy to find, and because it is only relevant to the `Present` class it makes sense to nest it. I would however document its inconsistency with `equals` as, [according to the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map).

i.e. as it now has a different "natural order" definition to equals, you may run into unforeseen problems in various circumstances.

You should also think about how you order two different Present objects that have the same cost - is ordering by cost all you need to do?

**Late edit** as far as your "second question" goes, you need to instantiate a new ArrayList each time you start the iterator, otherwise every map value refers to the same arraylist (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27969006/1945631) for more explanation):

```
for (GiftList giftList : giftSelector){
    presentList = new ArrayList<Present>; // create a new instance of a present list with each iteration otherwise ...
```